# My employer doesn't provide an electronic pay stub and I need one to get a car loan

Tags: loans, payroll

I have gotten a pay stub from every job I've held previously, but my new job is a small business and they do not give electronic pay stubs. I am given a handwritten statement showing what is withheld, but I went to get a loan through Subaru on a used car and they would not accept what I have been given.

I am in Vermont. I believe my employer is not required to provide an electronic statement. If this is the case, is there any way for Subaru to accept what I have?

Comment: Do you get a check or is it direct deposit? You might be able to show several months worth of bank statements or copies of the checks to show they are payroll checks.

Comment: You might also ask your employer if they'd be willing to provide a letter verifying your income, or some kind of pay statement, and ask the lender if they'd accept that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options and sometimes challenges help us improve our situation.

First, you can not borrow to buy a car.  Reducing the massive depreciation that cars undergo will help you be wealthier.  It is hard to find a good use car that you can buy for cash, but it will play out best for your finances in the long run.

If your heart is set on borrowing, I would encourage you to go to the bank/credit union where you have your checking account.  They will see your history of deposits and may grant you a loan based on that.  Also you are likely to get a better deal from the bank than from the car dealer.

Thirdly, you can simply go to your employer's HR department and ask them.  Surely someone has applied for a loan during the company's history.  What did they do for them?

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was getting a notarized copy of my withholdings and a statement from my employer saying what I earn hourly and annually.

I checked all my options first -- I could not get a bank loan as I did not have enough credit, I previously owned two used cars payed for with cash and wanted a reliable long-term vehicle.

My employer was a family-run 3-person office, with only one technical employee and 2 co-owners (so no HR department and no one the one employee had not needed a loan). Luckily one of the co-owners was a notary so it was very easy to have done in the office!